# VueJs Environment Variables Priority

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I have a VueJS application that uses different environment files as documented here:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#

I have 2 files in particular:

**.env.development**

I expect this file to be used when application runs in **remote development server**. It contains the following.

```
VUE_APP_K8S=true
VUE_APP_MATOMO_SITE_ID=0
```

**.env.development.local**

I expect this file to be used when application runs in **local development environment**. It contains the following.

```
VUE_APP_K8S=false
VUE_APP_MATOMO_SITE_ID=0
VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_PORT=5433
```

I would like to know if the file **.env.development.local** will be used in priority when running in **remote development server**? Or will it be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the example in the docs, you'll see that both these files are dependent on the mode, so if you run this command:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode development
```

it will use `.env.development` and if you run:

```
vue-cli-service serve --mode development
```

it should use `.env.development.local`

but you can also use `.env.local` which will always be loaded when you run locally, even without defining the mode.

So to summarize:

1. on remote dev, run the command: `vue-cli-service build --mode development` and `.env.development` will be loaded
2. on local env, run: `vue-cli-service serve --mode development` or change `.env.development.local` to `.env.local`

Answer (score 0):

`local` ENV files should not be committed into the repo. Only thing which makes them local is the fact, that default `.gitignore` file is set to ignore them. If you commit them into the repo, it will be loaded on your remote dev server (takes priority over `.env.development`)

Comment: Yes I've read about this but there is a number of local dev configuration variables that we want to share with our developers so that they can bootstrap the project easily

Comment: well then those variables are not local and should not go to a `.local` file....